# What event should be subscribed in RingCentral to get notified when a call is received?

Tags: subscription, webhooks, ringcentral

I'm working on an application where I need to get notified when a call is received on the main line or any of the available extensions. Which event should be subscribed to get notification?

Moreover does RingCentral support Webhook notification?
At some place I came across something which said RingCentral only supports PubNub but I saw that there is a way to provide TransportType as PubNub or Webhook.

Answer (score 2):

### Which event should be subscribed to get notification of a call being received on my main line or any of the available extensions?

You would want to subscribe to Presence events making sure to set the `detailedTelephonyStatus` query parameter to `true`.

Here is an example of this from the documentation for creating a subscription to presence events:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/subscription HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer U0pDMDFQMDFQQVMwMnxBQUJFU3VOMlp2bjZFR0gxNFhfTUNONhaU1SVHc
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 235


{
    "eventFilters": [
        "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true&aggregated=true"
    ],
    "deliveryMode": {
        "transportType": "PubNub",
        "encryption": "true"
    }
}
```

Within the `eventFilters` property, you would want to add an array element for each extension within the account which you wish to monitor.

I have created a sample application built in Node.js for creating a subscription to all of the extensions within a RingCentral sandbox account here: https://github.com/bdeanindy/ringcentral-subscription-basics.

### Does RingCentral support Webhook notification?

Yes, read the documentation for creating subscriptions  https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefCreateSubscription and you will see that both `PubNub` and `Webhook` are supported **transportType**.

Here is an example of how to create a subscription which uses the `Webhook` **transportType**:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/subscription HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer U0pDMDFQMDFQQVMwMXxBQURIZjAzWFFySGpMen
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 269

{
  "eventFilters": [
     "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence",
     "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store"
  ],
  "deliveryMode": {
        "transportType": "WebHook",
        "address": "https://consumer-host.example.com/consumer/path"
  }
}
```

You'll want to make sure to change the `deliveryMode.address` value to point to a server you manage to receive the events. This server will need to have a valid certificate chain supporting connections on port 443.

Here is a [quick start tutorial on using RingCentral Webhooks](http://ringcentral-quickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks/).

Comment: Does PHP SDK support registering Webhook Subscription?

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-php

Comment: Registering a subscription is just like any other REST API call, so yes the PHP SDK does support that since it provides a generic HTTP client with integrated OAuth. I also have a demo webhook app using Node and Express here: https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-demos-webhooks

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful.

Comment: In the case of the webhook we will also have to change the event filters to this "        "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true&aggregated=true"
"
is that correct?